# Como comunicar dados do JavaScript em JSF?

Tags: javascript, jsf, java-ee, aplicação-web, assinatura-digital

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que realiza assinatura digital. Nela, eu carrego um arquivo `PDF` que tem o endereço armazenado em uma variável `JavaScript`.
Em segundo plano, existe uma aplicação em `JSF`, que possui natureza de assinar o meu arquivo `PDF`.

O que preciso, é que o `JSF` consiga obter o arquivo para assinatura através da minha aplicação `JavaScript`.

Alguém saberia me dizer como poderia direcionar esses dados do `JavaScript` para o `JSF`?

Alguém já desenvolveu aplicações de assinatura digital, e saberia me explicar melhor como obter arquivos para assinatura de outras aplicações?

Comment: Se a aplicação JSF obter o endereço do arquivo já resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que passar esse "endereço" para o seu JSF. Poderá passa-lo incluindo ele em algum campo do formulário que será submetido ou poderá fazer isso direto com javascript usando a API js do JSF: http://www.javabeat.net/jsf-2-ajax-javascript-library/